# Google Cloud Status Check using REST API?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking for a REST API using which we can check the status of the Job. I am working in ServiceNow to do the Provision of the Virtual Instance using the REST API calls. I was able to create the REST calls successfully and the response received from the REST calls states that the STATUS:PENDING.

So, I want to check if the status has been changed from STATUS:PENDING to STATUS:DONE/READY. I want to check this using the REST API Call, is there any REST API call to check this.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/compute/v1/

The above link is used in google  API console to do Various Operations on VM.

Comment: Are you asking how to query the status of an instance that you've just launched? You can use compute.instances.get (see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get).

Answer (score 1):

You can send a GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/zones/zone/instances/instance.

This will return an [Instance Resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#resource), which contains a `status` property.

You can find more info about the CE REST API [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/).

You can also check out this example in Java of sending a GET request based on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get#examples)

```
public class ComputeExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Authentication is provided by the 'gcloud' tool when running locally
    // and by built-in service accounts when running on GAE, GCE, or GKE.
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

    // The createScopedRequired method returns true when running on GAE or a local developer
    // machine. In that case, the desired scopes must be passed in manually. When the code is
    // running in GCE, GKE or a Managed VM, the scopes are pulled from the GCE metadata server.
    // For more information, see
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(
              Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    Compute computeService =
        new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google Cloud Platform Sample")
            .build();

    // TODO: Change placeholders below to appropriate parameter values for the 'get' method:

    // * Project ID for this request.
    String project = "";

    // * The name of the zone for this request.
    String zone = "";

    // * Name of the instance resource to return.
    String instance = "";

    Compute.Instances.Get request = computeService.instances().get(project, zone, instance);
    Instance response = request.execute();

    //I'm assuming there's a getStatus method here
    String status = response.getStatus(); 
   }
}
```